# Access-Control-Allow-Origin OPENCART NO SOLUTION

Tags: javascript, .htaccess, cors, opencart

I got a problem with my website, as you know in the opencart, we have **config.php**  which can handle HTTP request, Here is code below:

```
define('HTTP_SERVER', 'http://www.DOMAIN.com/');
define('HTTPS_SERVER', 'https://www.DOMAIN.com/');
```

website will work well if we enter the website **www.** DOMAIN.com
but it won't work without **www.**   for example: http://DOMAIN.com

and If we will remove **www.** from **config.php** then website will work well.

I believe the problem is cause of **Access-Control-Allow-Origin**

I tried to use following code in **.htaccess**

```
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers "origin, x-requested-with, content-type"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS"
```

***By adding above code, website will work but not full functionally.***
But still the problem is exist in jquery-2.1.1.min.js

```
catalog/view/javascript/jquery/jquery-2.1.1.min.js
```

So, Please guide me how to make it work for both of them?

For example:        **Domain.com**    and   **www.domain.com**

Comment: This looks like a typo: `define('HTTPS_SERVER', 'http://www.DOMAIN.com/');`.  You are missing the `httpS`

Comment: It's not related to ssl, or https, this problem is cause of some other issues that's why I posted this question here.

Comment: Stop hosting your website on two different hostnames. Set up a redirect from `example.com` to `www.example.com`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://sx.xyz.com' is therefore not allowed access.**

I had also faced a similar problem with Cross Domain Data Exchange in the Ajax response as **error undefined**. But the response in header was **Status Code:200 OK**

```
Failed to load https://www.Domain.in/index.php?route=api/synchronization/checkapikey: 
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. 
Origin 'https://sx.xyz.in' is therefore not allowed access.
```

**The Solution:** In my case I had to call the function checkapikey() via Ajax to other Domain and get the response with data to where the call has made

```
if (($this->request->server['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') && isset($this->request->server['HTTP_ORIGIN'])) {

        $this->response->addHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: ' . $this->request->server['HTTP_ORIGIN']);
        $this->response->addHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS');
        $this->response->addHeader('Access-Control-Max-Age: 1000');
        $this->response->addHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
        $this->response->addHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Authorization, X-Requested-With');

        $headers = getallheaders();
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After configer to http://www.DOMAIN.com/, put these lines into .htaccess file located on the OpenCart root folder. If you don’t have that file, you’ll have to create it first.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

These rules will redirect all non-www traffic to your domain www version to avoid the cross-domain conflict. Some additional difficulties you may experience due to the explained conflict are session lost after login and incomplete orders after PayPal check our due to incorrect call back URL settings. The above configuration should resolve all of the mentioned issues.

Answer (score 0):

Open this file : system/library/url.php
. And look for **if ($this->ssl && $secure) {**

delete these codes (in 2 locations)

```
'https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] .
```

Your code block should look like this:

```
if ($this->ssl && $secure) {
            //$url = 'https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . rtrim(dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']), '/.\\') . '/index.php?route=' . $route;
            $url = rtrim(dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']), '/.\\') . '/index.php?route=' . $route;
        } else {
            //$url = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . rtrim(dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']), '/.\\') . '/index.php?route=' . $route;
            $url =  rtrim(dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']), '/.\\') . '/index.php?route=' . $route;
        }
```

Please take note, I comment out original codes,make duplicate under it, then I removed **'https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']**

Optional:
You will get bunch of 'Notice' errors when you refresh your page. Take this extra step:
Open catalog/controller/startup/seo_url
replace :

```
 return $url_info['scheme'] . '://' . $url_info['host'] . (isset($url_info['port']) ? ':' . $url_info['port'] : '') . str_replace('/index.php', '', $url_info['path']) . $url . $query;
```

by

```
return (isset($url_info['port']) ? ':' . $url_info['port'] : '') . str_replace('/index.php', '', $url_info['path']) . $url . $query;
```